# Create buttons like product hunt

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I would like to create buttons like this where there is a button name and an icon in left of it and when you hover over **Tech** an extra side button "+" appears like this [image] and when you totally hover over extra two buttons appear [image]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance. To see it live functioning, here is the link of it : https://www.producthunt.com/e/best-of-february-2017

Answer (score 1):

I have tried my level best to create

Here is the Code

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #BDBDBD;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  color: #212121;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transition: all linear 0.2s;
}
.btn span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #9E9E9E;
  border-left: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
  width: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.btn:hover {
  padding-right: 30px;
  background-color: #9E9E9E;
}
.btn:hover span {
  width: auto;
  visibility: visible;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
```

```html
<span class="btn">
designer
  <span>+</span>
</span>
```

[Link for reference](https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/dRzwzW?editors=1100)

hope this helps..

Comment: wow ! thanks a lot.. Do you have any idea of the right side four buttons?